How to use UAExpert OPC UA client to store the alarms that are shown in Events View as CSV on Desktop?
I want to make a C# based Emailing client, that would send emails to concerned peoples depending on alarms that come from the CNC machine (Siemens Sinumerik ONE controller).
So far I have found that I can read alarms on the UAExpert OPC UA client, but don't know how to export those alarms from events view to some file on desktop which I can read through my C# app.
Or is there any possiblity of creating a OPC UA client just to read those alarms ?

You can create a client directly in C# to subscribe to the OPC UA alarms and send emails. Due to the complexity of OPC UA, you will need to use some OPC UA client library. You can go with a "free" option, such as https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard . Or with a commercial toolkit, such as QuickOPC (disclaimer: I am the author of it), https://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc/opc-specifications/unified-architecture/alarms-conditions . The code to subscribe to the alarms can then look like this:
// The callback is a lambda expression that displays the event 
EasyUAClient.SharedInstance.SubscribeEvent(
    "opc.tcp://opcua.demo-this.com:62544/Quickstarts/AlarmConditionServer", 
    UAObjectIds.Server,
    1000,
    (_, args) => Console.WriteLine(args));

